# Redirect old wordpress URLs to new site root w/ htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site whos old urls look something like this

```
domain.com/wordpress/
domain.com/wordpress/?page_id=301 ect...
```

and i want them to redirect to just a bare '`domain.com`'

how do I do this in htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this redirect rule as very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} . [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]
```